# cant find a way to insert RecycleView inside fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment

I'm am new to Kotlin I try to create a Shopping List app and I encountered a problem with a RecycleView inside a fragment.
In the fragment, I have a button that a user click and adds `Item` to the list but I got error when I tried to add the layout manager inside the `OnCreateView` function.
I tried this:

```
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container, false)


        rv_shoppinglist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) \\ this is where i get ERR

        return view
    }
```

and i got an ERR -> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: rv_shoppinglist must not be null`

So i  added this line `rv_shoppinglist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)`
on different function

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        rv_shoppinglist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    }
```

and now the app works and when I user add the item to the list it does show the items on the RecycleView but instead of displaying them line underline it's displaying them with a screen size gap
Image:
[image]

edit:
This is the XML file for RV_CHILD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is an XML file for shopping_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.shopping_list">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_shoppinglist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_shoppiglist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the xml for the layout file you are using to represent your RecyclerViews list items

Comment: Maybe your ViewHolder layout has height of "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content"?

Comment: Please add your xml layout file for recycler view and recycler view items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set relative layouts height to `wrap_content` otherwise it will take up the whole screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter pointed out, it appears that your viewholder layout height (RV_CHILD in your case) is set to `match_parent` when it should probably be `wrap_content`